# Android preview configurations in Intellij IDEA 12

Tags: android, android-layout, intellij-idea

There is a nice layout preview in Intellij IDEA. I remember in version 11 I could add my own configuration with specific density and screen size. It was `Edit` button in this list:

[image: Layout preview]

In the new version 12 I can't see it. How can I create my own configuration now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **AVD Manager** (Android Virtual Device Manager) from Android SDK distribution, you can add more devices in the **Device Definitions** tab:

[image: AVD]